# regex replacement for whole object tree / reverse operation to `tostring`

Tags: jq

So I have big json, where I need to take some subtree and copy it to other place, but with some properties updated (a lot of them). So for example:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "id": 1, "other": "abc"},
    { "id": 2, "other": "def"},
    { "id": 3, "other": "ghi"}
  ]
}
```

and say, that i'd like to duplicate record having id == 2, and replace char `e` in `other` field with char `x` using regex. That could go (I'm sure there is a better way, but I'm beginner) something like:

```
jq '.items |= . + [.[]|select (.id == 2) as $orig | .id=4 | .other=($orig.other | sub("e";"x"))]'<sample.json
```

producing

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "other": "abc"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "other": "def"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "other": "ghi"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "other": "dxf"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now that's great. But suppose, that there ins't just one `other` field. There are multitude of them, and over deep tree. Well I can issue multiple `sub` operations, but assuming, that replacement pattern is sufficiently selective, maybe we can turn the whole JSON subtree to string (trivial, tostring method) and replace all occurences using singe sub call. But how to turn that substituted string back to — is it call object? — to be able to add it back to items array?

Comment: In the general problem you're trying to solve, you say there are a multitude of `other` fields, so you will need to specify a bit more precisely what the general problem is.  Are the "other" fields known ahead of time or must they be inferred from the input JSON?  What if the items in an `.items` array are not uniform?  E.g. if some of them don't have an .id field? Or if some of them have an "other" field but some don't?

Comment: Items in `items` need not to be uniform in principle. But we're selecting one by ID and this one will have known structure. All replaced fields will be strings. The general problem is, that item of ID 2 from our example has some depth, say 5. And there are strings on all levels which contains <text to be replaced> which we need to replace with something else, but otherwise the whole `item` will remain the same. Because of that, I'd say that structure is not important. I can write half-page long of replacements if I list every property to be fixed, that not a problem. I'm looking for easier way

Comment: regarding "what if some of them does not have id" — then we won't select the item and wont duplicate it. It is like: select item in array somehow (in our case by id), after that item is found (axiom), take it's subtree and do regex replacement on every string in that subtree, result add to items array. If I could do: `select item form items array | tostring | sub("a";"b")` I'd posses correct JSON (assume). All I need to do is to put it somehow into items array. No idea how.

Comment: Ok, I was overlooking function fromjson. So maybe this is the solution:
`jq '.items |= . + [.[]|select (.id == 2) as $orig | .id=4 | tostring | gsub("e";"x") | fromjson ]'<sample.json` — in this case the pattern "e" is very inspecific, thus it's applied where it shouldn't be, but this is generally probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a program that might be a solution to the general problem you are describing, but if not at least illustrates how problems of this type can be solved. Note in particular that there is no explicit reference to a field named "other", and that (thanks to `walk`) the update function is applied to all candidate JSON objects in the input.

```
def update($n):
  if .items | length > 0
  then ((.items[0]|keys_unsorted) - ["id"]) as $keys
  | if ($keys | length) == 1 
    then $keys[0] as $key
    | (.items|map(.id) | max + 1) as $newid
    | .items |= . + [.[] | select(.id == $n) as $orig | .id=$newid | .[$key]=($orig[$key] | sub("e";"x"))]
    else .
    end
  else .
  end;

walk(if type == "object" and has("items") then update(2) else . end)
```

Comment: thanks! This is a little bit over my experience right now, but I'll study it to learn from it. Thanks again for your great help(as usual)!